# How to do multiple main class that generates source code in maven

Tags: java, maven

how do this in maven pom.xml when i run mvn clean install in one single module ?

1. Compile main source code
2. Call main class inside source code that is compiled to generate another source code
3. Group no 1 and 2 and execute compile again
4. During package phase the original source code plus generated source code should be in the jar

Comment: You definitely don't want that. Whatever you are trying to achieve, this is not the right process for it.

Comment: Thx . i am just exploring these as way not to introduce multiple module for generator. I can introduce 2 maven module . 1 is for my code generator , 2nd will depends on 1st one and i can run my code generation and put in "add-sources" phase so it get bundle in the jar . I m just thinking whether i can do this in one module . in gradle i can intercept the compile phase and do these stuff . in maven seems not that easy

Comment: Split it up. you construct a way to complicated process that nobody will understand besides you and that, in case of error, is very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh. Your task seems fairly weird to me. Anyway, you could just write a script. I come from Gradle, but it's analogue to Maven, so: Create a task `buildPipeline`.

`buildPipeline` depends on `buildProjectA`, `buildProjectB` and a copy task, *e.g.* `copySourceA`.

- `buildProjectA` builds source of `ProjectA`. Maven/Gradle merely looks at sources resources and builds the project in a regular fashion.
- `copySourceA` ensures to copy whatever you need of codebase A to codebase B, which is elsewhere. `copySourceA` depends on `buildProjectA`.
- finally `buildSourceB` depends on `copySourceA` (or `mustRunAfter` it), so that when `buildSourceB` is triggered, the assumption can be made, that A is built and its sources copied.

If you need to do something else, like executing a script in order to run / build something, you can swap the copy task for anything else, Gradle is able to call executables and I suppose Maven can too.

Finally I will say two things. So far I do not understand what you mean by

> Call main class inside source code

If anything I imagine you call a JAR, where its main class is the entry point for a process to build the other project?...

Be that as it may - this all sounds like a pretty messed up project structure to me, so maybe you should refactor the code properly. Especially if this is something you have to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thx . i am just exploring these as way not to introduce multiple module for generator. I can introduce 2 maven module . 1 is for my code generator , 2nd will depends on 1st one and i can run my code generation and put in "add-sources" phase so it get bundle . I m just thinking whether i can do this in one module . in gradle  i can intercept the compile phase and do these stuff . in maven seems not that easy

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions i tried and works . 
Basically you force to call maven compiler plugin again after u generate additional java code generated

```
<plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-code</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                            <mainClass>MyClassGenerator</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>${generated.code.dir}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>addtoSourceFolder</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${generated.code.dir}</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-generated-code</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>**/*.java</includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```